# Which question to be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I recently had a question of mine marked as a duplicate: [How to force @media print for automated test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416998/how-to-force-media-print-for-automated-test).  I was surprised because I try to avoid that kind of thing.  Upon further investigation, I'm confused as to why mine was marked as a duplicate.  My question was posted in 2015, the question that mine was supposedly a duplicate of wasn't asked until 2017 and even refers back to my question in the description: [How to test @media print with protractor or selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088732/how-to-test-media-print-with-protractor-or-selenium).

It seems that the new question should be marked as the duplicate, not the older?  Is there more to this that I'm missing?

Comment: the best dupe target isn't always the oldest question.

Comment: Yours didn't have any answers so the other one could not be closed setting yours as the target.